# SSIS destination CSV file getting bad data

Tags: ssis

I have developed one  SSIS package where I need to take records from database and send it in CSV file. While doing so I found that the csv file when opened in excel is showing some column records with = sign eg "=D7". Can you please suggest how to overcome the issue? Thanks,pallabi

Comment: Can you give more information please? Screenshot of Excel? What are the column values before writing them to the CSV? What are the values looking like in the CSV?